# Module/plugin to show thumbnails only in homepage

Tags: php, joomla

Is there any module/plugin to show thumbnails only in homepage?
In my article page I'll upload many images but i want to show a different image when this article will be shown in homepage.

Comment: I don't get it? You want to show some images just in the homepage ?
But the Homepage you show it only in the real homepage, i mean there isn't a second homepage, in that case it's just another "article".

Comment: Im sorry but I also have no idea what you mean. Can you please be more specific

Comment: when I add as image in an article, the image appears at the article and homepage, because my homepage show the latest articles. but i want to put as unique image at home, with a specific width and height, and i can't it shown at article page, only as a thumbnail of my article in my homepage.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a CSS class applied to the thumbnail e.g. on a Front page or a Category Blog listing which shows the text before a "Read More..." link we show a small thumb.

On an actual article page though the only the main image is visible as the CSS hides the thumbnail on article pages. Obviously depending on your Joomla! you will have to use the appropriate selectors, I've included an example from a site we have in development.

The CSS for the Featured/Blog pages:

```
div.featured .blogthumb, div.blog .blogthumb, #tinymce .blogthumb {
    display: block;
}
```

*The CSS above includes the `#tinymce` **id**, so that the thumbnail is still visible in the editor after applying the  `.blogthumb` class to the image.*

While the CSS for the rest of the site looks like this:

```
.blogthumb {
    display: none;
}
```

As mentioned before this CSS is specific to the template we're using - you will have to investigate the equivalent ID's or classes for your template.